# Diagram tool for actors

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

Is there any thing that can generate a sequence diagram between actors in akka?

Or any kind of diagram in akka?
I use sbt 0.13.13 with scala 2.11.8, akka 2.4.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of general visualization of akka actors (mailboxes) is quite fresh, so there is not much in terms of existing frameworks for it. The one I came around and seemed closest to kind of general solution was [akka-visualmailbox](https://github.com/ouven/akka-visualmailbox).

They also have [sample project](https://github.com/ouven/akka-visualmailbox/tree/master/sample-project) and comprehensive installation instructions in [README](https://github.com/ouven/akka-visualmailbox/blob/master/README.md).

The best part of this one is that it does not require code changes.

Another one that does is [akka-message-visualization](https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/akka-message-visualization) however I did not see any simple setup guides out there for it.

Comment: akka-message-visualization was just my proof of concept, that I didn't have the time to turn into something else. However some guys from my city managed to do something like this: https://github.com/blstream/akka-viz which might be more of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lightbend Telemetry [Visualization tools](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/cinnamon/2.6.x/visualizations/visualizations.html)

- Specially look into [Vizceral](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/cinnamon/2.6.x/visualizations/vizceral.html) Visualization tool

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building one called [Muse](https://github.com/sirolf2009/muse), it's still in early stages, but I have already begun using it at the office. You can select one or more messages and generate a sequence diagram from them.